# Why "POSITION:RELATIVE" messes up things?

Tags: css-position

If you enable `position:relative` for the right one, you will see that it overflows the left one:

http://jsfiddle.net/bfwhoem5/1/

why? 
How to solve that (while maintaining `position:relative` too). Also, I want when mouseover with INSPECT, the right one should not be overflowed over left.

p.s. I dont wish `calc`, because it is not yet well supported...

Answer (score 1):

Here is one solution:

```css
#left {
  position:relative;
 float:left; width:180px; background:#ff0000;
}
#right {
  position:relative; 
 width: calc(100% - 180px); background:#00FF00;float:left;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <div id="left">
  leftttt
 </div>
 <div id="right">
  rightttt
 </div>
</div>
```

Your issue is with one div having a float and the other not - also if you are going to put two items side by side you cannot have one with a width of 100%, either they will go on top of each other or go to the next line depending on their position relative to each other.

Comment: I upvote your answer, however, i dont like CALC (not widely supported) yet. Is there any method?